# Getting value from Edit to work with region

Tags: c++, arrays, image, c++builder, region

I needed to divide the picture into sectors and count the number of black dots in each of them. I use regions for this. Can I do this with the Edit input field somehow?

```
HRGN region [n];
```

HRGN requires a constant value like

```
const n = 35;
```

Please, help if it is possible to somehow link HRGN with Edit, for example, if Edit is set as follows:

```
int n = Edit1-> Text.ToIntDef (0);
```

Comment: What picture? What sectors? What black dots? What regions? Can you try to pretend that a complete stranger walks into the room, and you'd like to ask the stranger a quesiton. You never met the stranger before. What would you ask the stranger?

Comment: And when you're talking to that stranger, the two of you are not in the same room as your computer, so they can't see what you're talking about as you're asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking how to allocate an array using a `TEdit` to specify the array's count, is that right?

Consider using [`T(C)SpinEdit`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Samples.Spin.TSpinEdit) instead of `TEdit` for numeric input.

You can allocate an array dynamically at runtime using `new[]`:

```cpp
HRGN *region = NULL;
...
int n = Edit1->Text.ToInt(); // or SpinEdit1->Value
region = new HRGN[n];
// use region as needed...
delete[] region;
```

Or better, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or [`System::DynamicArray`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DynamicArray), instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>
std::vector<HRGN> region;
...
int n = Edit1->Text.ToInt(); // or SpinEdit1->Value
region.resize(n);
// use region as needed...
// freed automatically when out of scope...
```

```cpp
#include <sysdyn.h>
DynamicArray<HRGN> region;
...
int n = Edit1-> Text.ToInt(); // or SpinEdit1->Value
region.Length = n;
// use region as needed...
// freed automatically when out of scope...
```